# How can I use variables in C++ without passing into a function

Tags: c++, function

Is there a way in C where you can use variables that you don't pass in variables?

I'm working on some code that someone else started on and I'm just modifying it.

Here is some code that I have.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void rotate90() {
    for (int w=0;w<n;w++) {
        for (int h=0;h<n;h++) {
            chart2[h][w]=chart[n1-w][n1-h];
        } 
    }
    for (int h=0;h<n;h++) {
        for (int w=0;w<n;w++) {
            chart[h][w]=chart2[h][w];
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    ......
        else
        {
            rotate90;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for global variables.

Comment: But you should probably just pass the data. The pain of refactoring will be less in the long run than that if using globals.

Comment: You can but its a bad practice. 1 letter variable names is also a bad practice.

Comment: Since the edit window has closed on my last comment. I would like to clarify the last part a little. variables used for a loop like `i`, `j` ... are fine but most other variables its best to give them meaningful names. You will be happy you did when you are debugging your code a year later when it fails..

Comment: `rotate90;` is a no-op and does not invoke the function.

Comment: @L.F. I would even emphasize that `rotate90;` is a _syntactically correct_ no-op. Hence, the compiler will not give an error. With reasonable settings, it should, at least, give a warning that the statement hasn't any effect... ;-)